# How to adapt height of div to its content while in flex wrapper

Tags: css, flexbox

I am working on flex css properties. I have found a pretty nice example of a basic template but I wish I could adapt some things : 
I want the nav section to only fit its own content. For now, because of the properties on the `.wrapper`, the height of the nav div is stretched down to the bottom of the page, and I need to keep these properties on the wrapper because I also need the footer to stay at the bottom.

I thought setting `flex: 0;` to the aside section would help but it doesn't change anything, and Im getting so lost now, that Im just messing up with the template. 
Any help please? Here is the template Im working on :
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QOrRxB?editors=1100

Thanks

Comment: `nav { align-self: flex-start }`

Comment: oh man.... I didn't find that one, though I read multiples topics. Thanks a lot, saving me some more hours of headache :)